# Import data from Excel file so the file is not locked from oher Users

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a linked data base to my front end of Access.

This Excel spreadsheet is updated quite frequently and whenever a user opens the front end it will also open the linked Excel spreadsheet in anther window, thus preventing anyone else trying to use that linked spreadsheet.

I've tried to come up with a couple different solutions and none have prevailed.

**Method 1:**

Using VBA to create a copy of the Excel file via the following line in a local directory every time the form is opened.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    FileCopy "\\calfs01\LOCATION_A\FILE.xlsx", _ 
    "\\calfs01\LOCATION_B\FILE.xlsx"

End Sub
```

I am receiving an error message indicating that I don't have the required permissions to copy it. I do however have permissions to access this file, as I can do it manually.

**Method 2:**

Instead of linking the Excel Spreadsheet, create a new table based of the data from the Excel Spreadsheet and have it update the table on Form_Load(). In the end I couldn't get this step to work, and unfortunately lost the code for it!
The issue with using an automated process is the first two lines in the Excel spreadsheet are headers, and I do not know a way around this issue.

**Method 3:**

Use a batch file to copy the Excel file, however the file is located on a network drive and (correct me if I'm wrong) cannot copy from a network drive.

**My main question here is what would be the best way to do the below steps?**

1. Copy the file locally (or on the network, as long as there is at least one copy for each user so there are not conflicting connection issues to the spreadsheet)
2. Link the file once copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way by far, in my opinion, is method 2. Unfortunately you lost the code, so I can't say where you've gone wrong.

There are LOADS of ways to import data from Excel files into Access. If you're having trouble because you have multiple headers, you can first [create a named range in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64), and then you can easily import just what you want.

A simple way to import is using a query (first row of named range is assumed to contain headers:

`CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT * INTO MyTemporaryTable FROM [MyNamedRange] IN '\\calfs01\LOCATION_A\FILE.xlsx'[Excel 12.0 Xml;];`

Or alternatively, using `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM MyTemporaryTable" 'First, empty the table
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "C", "\\calfs01\LOCATION_A\FILE.xlsx", True, "MyNamedRange"
```

If the size of your range is constantly changing, it's a little more difficult, but certainly possible.

Comment: So if I'm using Method 2, do you have anything I can use as a reference to help me with this method? Tutorial of some sort? Also, when importing this, is it possible to change the name of each column with this process? There are 181 columns, I don't mind doing it manually 1 at a time for the code, as long as it's a one time thing and doesn't need to be done every time I open the data base

Comment: Using both approaches for method two, you can actually state column names (first approach would be something like `SELECT F1 As ColumnA, F2 As Column2 etc FROM etc`, second approach inserts into an existing table and uses its column names). I don't have a tutorial (you can read the official documentation for [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access), just wrote up those 2 approaches. I'm linking in my answer for a quick guide for named ranges, though.